# Trimble GeoXH vs GeoXT and GPS Correct

Tags: gps, arcpad

I am about to purchase a new GPS unit. I currently have a GeoXT and have used the combo of GPS Correct/ArcPad with GPS Analyst/ArcMap to correct the collected data to submeter (or close to it).

Looking at the GeoXH specs, it will already collect data at submeter. So if I use GPS Correct with a GeoXH, how much more accurate will it be? Will it just verify that my data has been collected at submeter accuracy or will it get corrected down to like subfoot accuracy or something?

I'm not familiar with technical details of GPS units, but was wondering if the upgrade to a GeoXH is worth the added cost?

Comment: What are you using the GPS units for example? - if cadastre you will require the best GeoXH (if not better) - if using for leisure geocaching then GeoXT is suitable.

Comment: Thanks. The data is used for collecting field data, like well locations or locating buried pipe.

Comment: Rene, any chance I could talk with you as regards the GeoXT? We just picked one up. I'd love to talk with someone with some experience with them.

Comment: Curious my self. Would be nice to just turn the GPS on and collect with sub-metre accuracy. I didn't know you can collect sub-metre data with these units without additional antenna and base stations. (I was once told by a trimble rep when wanting to collect sub-metre data in the far north that this cannot be done with just the handheld because of the location. I suspect accuracy depends on proximity to base stations as well. I might be wrong but I believe that for real time correction the unit must be able to "connect" with the base stations so it might need to access some type of network?)

Comment: The GPS chips and software (firmware) inside have greatly improved - the most important factor is the number of satellite fixes the GPS unit can get at that point in time minimum is 4, 8-16 better (weather and solar weather can still affect the results).

Comment: Can you provide any feedback on the Trimble you have been using?  Also, are you interested in selling the Trimble as I'm looking to purchase one this quarter.  Thanks, Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the GeoXH with an external "Hurricane" antenna for sub-meter location using both Terrasync and Arcpad.  With no canopy or obstructions and with longer fixes we have gotten close to foot level accuracy without a base station.

Answer (score 0):

Any updates on this?
I am interested if anyone has had a use case for recording the location of buried pipe with gps, presenting the data on gis, and subsequently locating the buried pipe. 
I have found that the gps in my new android phone, sony dsc-hx5 and garmin gps 12 are not really discernable, all being around 15 m.

I see the next threshold for accuracy above my Garmin GPS12 is the unit http://www.sxbluegps.com/sxblueII-L-gps.html  US$3.5K
We don't have the option of any coast beacons or the like, only the omnistar satellite dgps signal, AFAIK.

I'd be interested in other experience.

I am also considering the use of doForms on the android device. 
I don't see any end to end solutions that are reasonably priced to capture data and display it to another user in the field.